# MoviePy Animation

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to animate a simple effect in moviepy. The first video needs to play. In its last 0.5s, the other video should slide in its place and start playing. The animation should be exactly 0.5s.

The script I wrote for some reason only works for the 1st and last videos. So if there are 2 videos, this will work. But for 3 videos, the middle video will appear black.

Also the script below breaks completely even for 2 videos if `delay` is not put in a separate variable, and `cumulative_duration - 0.5` is passed directly to the 2 functions.

Does anyone know what this mystery is?

```
from moviepy.editor import CompositeVideoClip, VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.fx.all import freeze


def overlay_with_animation(videos):
    clips = [VideoFileClip(video) for video in videos]
    w = clips[0].w
    h = clips[0].h

    def slide(t, shift):
        slide_duration = 0.5
        x = max(w - w * max(t - shift, 0) / slide_duration, 0)
        y = 0
        return x, y

    cumulative_duration = 0

    for i in range(len(clips)):
        if i > 0:
            # Calculate the delay for the slide-in effect
            delay = cumulative_duration - 0.5
            # Add the freeze effect to the beginning of the clip
            clips[i] = freeze(clips[i], t=0, freeze_duration=delay)
            # Set the slide-in position for the clip
            clips[i] = clips[i].set_position(lambda t: slide(t, delay))

        cumulative_duration += clips[i].duration

    final_clip = CompositeVideoClip(clips, size=(w, h))
    final_clip.write_videofile("merged.mp4", fps=24)
```